# Powershell to list All Activated Features in All Site Collections 2010/2013

Tags: powershell, site, features, collection

Need a powershell script to list all activated features, for all site collections/webs and to output to a csv, per Site Collection and to work on both 2010/2013.

Have seen things like this for a single SC but need it to re-iterate through ALL SCs in a Web App:

```
#------ Include the SharePoint cmdlets
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    $SP_SiteCollection = "https://SPWebApp"

Get-SPSite $SP_SiteCollection | % {

$results = @()

Get-SPFeature -Site $_ -Limit All | % {

$feature = $_; 
    $featuresDefn = (Get-SPFarm).FeatureDefinitions[$_.ID]; 
    $cc = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture;

    $obj = New-Object PSObject;
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Title  $($featuresDefn.GetTitle($cc));
    $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty  Hidden $($feature.Hidden);

    $results += $obj;
}
$results | FT -auto;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, mister:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
    $webapp = "http://webapplication"

$results = @()

$webapp | Get-SPSite -Limit All | % {
    $siteCol = $_.RootWeb.Url
    Get-SPFeature -Site $_ | % {
        $feature = $_; 
        $obj = New-Object PSObject;
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Title $($feature.DisplayName);
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Hidden $($feature.Hidden);
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Url $($siteCol);
        $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Type "Site Feature";

        $results += $obj;
    }

    $_.AllWebs | % {
         $web = $_.Url
         Get-SPFeature -Web  $_ -Limit All | % {
            $feature = $_; 
            $obj = New-Object PSObject;
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Title $($feature.DisplayName);
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Hidden $($feature.Hidden);
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Url $($web);
            $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Type "Web Feature";

            $results += $obj;
        }
    }
}

$results | export-csv -path E:\Powershell\features.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Refactor as appropriate :)

Edit: Updated the script to include Site/Web Url with every feature.

Comment: Nice, thanks, BUT just gives me a big list of activated Features.....need it listed per SC so can look at individual SCs and see what features are there SC by SC

Comment: Well, should have added that in the question then :) Add a variable after `$webapp | Get-SPSite -Limit All | % {` which would get the site url (`$siteurl = $_.RootWeb.Url`), then add it to the `$obj` the same way as `Title`, `Hidden`, and `Type`. Do the same with the web in the second loop.

Comment: Sorry Paul, not sure what you mean...My PS is VERY basic.....I run commandletes with a few switches, not script with them! Need to be spoonfed here :)  Appreciating the assistance here tho!

Comment: Updated the answer. Now it adds a URL with every feature. You will be able to filter what you want with Excel.

Comment: Awesome Paul! Get what you did there now, thanks! Also added this: $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty ID $($feature.ID); so I could get the feature ID, which works, but then tried to add this: $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty Site ID $($siteCol.ID); to get the Site ID, which failed. Is there a way that I can query the available (site?) objects so I can get the correct format to extract the Site ID?

Comment: Oh, come on! :) Change `$siteCol = $_.RootWeb.Url` to `$siteCol = $_.RootWeb` then `Url $($siteCol);` to `Url $($siteCol.Url)`. Next change `$web = $_.Url` to `$web = $_` and `Url $($web);` to `Url $($web.Url);`. Then your `$($siteCol.ID)` should work just fine. Keep in mind that `NoteProperty` should have the same name when adding Sites and Webs to the `$results`, otherwise that will not work.

Comment: LOL, did say you would have to spoonfeed me!! I'm an Administrator not a Developer! :) Nice one, though truly appreciated!

Comment: One of the most important things SP Administrators should learn is PowerShell :) Enjoy.